# Evaluating a Survival Analysis model

Tags: survival, model-selection

I have just begun studying survival analysis and I am using it for an industrial problem where I am trying to build survival curves for customer liftimes (from when they sign-up to when they cancel).  I am using the Aalen additive model using explanatory variables that I think affect the customer lifetime.

What I am having trouble understanding is the following.  What I am really interested in are the survival curves of active customers (i.e. censored).  This way I can get some insight into how likely they are to cancel given how long they have been a customer.  Coming from a ML background, I find it troubling to train the Aalen model with data points that I am interested in testing (i.e. overfitting).  So would it be a better idea to only train the model on cancelled accounts, then test it on the active ones?

I guess a generalized version of my question would be how do you know if your SA model is overfitting?  This particular model uses regression, so wouldn't overfitting be a possible issue?  Perhaps I am completely missing the point of SA and maybe it is not meant for prediction in this way